# Reverse Geocoding NPM node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, geocoding

I'm trying to use the package reverse-geocoding https://www.npmjs.com/package/reverse-geocoding

The documentation I think isn't right because it gives me a the next error

`TypeError: geocoding.location is not a function`

my function is:

```
var geocoding = new require('reverse-geocoding');
var config = {
    'latitude': 40.00403611111111,
    'longitude': 116.48485555555555
};
geocoding.location(config, function (err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at index.js of the package reveals that the export looks like this:

```
module.exports = function (config, callback) { ... }
```

The example code is indeed wrong, and should look something like this:

```
var geocoding = new require('reverse-geocoding');
var config = {
    'latitude': 40.00403611111111,
    'longitude': 116.48485555555555
};
geocoding(config, function (err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Note that I get an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT message, so you may want to change the module so it uses a different API key.